# Does not change default value in mysql (laravel 5,5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

this is my code in users tabel (migrations)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('level')->default('user');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

when I want to change level manually like below code

```
    return User::create([
        'level' => 'admin',
        'name' => 'emad',
        'email' => 'emad@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('123456')
    ]);
```

In the level field, the same user value is saved and admin dosent save.
I do not know why?

Comment: Add your code for the user model

Comment: @carrion oh , I think I understood , problem is fillable. thanks.

Comment: Ok glad to help, good luck on your project

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the little code here, i would say you haven't added the `level` column to the fillable model variable.Like so:

```
protected $fillable = ['level','any_other_field_you_want_to_assign'];
```

Add this line of code to the top of your User model class

Check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: That would be my guess too!